# modelform: override clean method

Tags: django, overriding, modelform, data-cleaning

I have two questions concerning the clean method on a modelform. Here is my example:

```
class AddProfileForm(ModelForm):
        ...
        password = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form2'}))
        password_verify = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form2'}), label='Retype password')
        ...

        class Meta:
            model = UserModel
            fields=("username", "password", "password_verify", "first_name", "last_name", "date_of_birth", "biography", "contacts", )

        #called on validation of the form
        def clean(self):
            #run the standard clean method first
            cleaned_data=super(AddProfileForm, self).clean()
            password = cleaned_data.get("password")
            password_verify = cleaned_data.get("password_verify")

            #check if passwords are entered and match
            if password and password_verify and password==password_verify:
                print "pwd ok"
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match!")

            #always return the cleaned data
            return cleaned_data
```

1. Should I always call the standard clean method?

   ```
   cleaned_data=super(AddProfileForm, self).clean()
   ```
2. Should I always return the cleaned_data variable?

   ```
   return cleaned_data
   ```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For 1, Yes, if you want to make use of parent class's validators. See this explanation on the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method).

> Warning
>
> The ModelForm.clean() method sets a flag that makes the model
>   validation step validate the uniqueness of model fields that are
>   marked as unique, unique_together or unique_for_date|month|year.
>
> If you would like to override the clean() method and maintain this
>   validation, you must call the parent class’s clean() method.

For 2, yes, if data validates properly. Otherwise raise validation error.

Comment: 1 / So if I don't call the parent class's clean method, the other fields won't be validated? In which case should this be useful ? (fields always must be validated, musn't they?) 2/ In my clean method, there can be a validation error but I return cleaned_data anyway! Is it a wrong way to do?

Comment: @rom, Fields are validated in their own `field_clean()` method. `clean()` method is to validate any combination or multiple fields with values relating to one another.

Comment: Ok so if I remove super(AddProfileForm, self).clean() it still works, no? Or it won't check the unique_together constraints (for example)?

Comment: @rom, please read the answer to find out when it shall be called.

Comment: Yes sorry, I just edited my previous comment, now I understand. What about the second point? (In my clean method, there can be a validation error but I return cleaned_data anyway! Is it a wrong way to do?)

Comment: @rom, Either you return `cleaned_data` with removing invalid fields, setting up errors for fields or raise validation error. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35963/discussion-between-rom-and-rohan)

Comment: Can you use an example to show how the super function is called? ie: should I return it? Should I call it in the beginning of my code or the end?